# Differentiate between different Strings in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a set of Types which are just strings, ie.

```
type FooId = string
type BarId = string

const callFoo = (id: FooId) => {}

const b: BarId = 'bar'

callFoo(b)
```

To me, that should error, because I'm passing a `BarID` when I need to pass a `FooID`

How can I tell TypeScript to give special meaning to these, essentially, strings?

More context:

```
import { monotonicFactory } from "ulid";

export type ULID = string;
export const ulid = monotonicFactory() as () => ULID;

type FooId = ULID
type BarId = ULID
```

They're all `ULID`'s, not just "strings"

Comment: The problem is that `BarId` is assignable to `FooId`, which means typescript won't complain because the types are compatible. You'll need to give typescript some aditional condition on the type for it to be able to differentiate between `FooId` and `BarId`

Comment: @MikeS. Yeah, i feared as much. Any ideas?

Comment: can you maybe provide us the actual difference between the Ids? are they like GUIDs or numbers, is there any kind of structure? I would probably use that and provide additional conditions to the type

Comment: this might give you some insights - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/nominal-typing

Comment: If you know which specific strings can be assigned to `FooId` and `BarId` you could use literal strings `type FooId = 'foo'`.  If they both can be any `string`, you may want to try `type FooId = {foo: string}` and `type BarId = {bar: string}`

Comment: `FooId` and `BarId` are just aliases of `string`. They are not different types. Check the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases). It clearly says _"Note that aliases are only aliases - you cannot use type aliases to create different/distinct “versions” of the same type. When you use the alias, it’s exactly as if you had written the aliased type."_.

Answer (score 0):

Let's utilize @basarat's TDD book: [Nominal Typing](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping)

Because you are using strings here, I think the enum method is the best choice:

```
enum FooBrand { _ = "" }
enum BarBrand { _ = "" }

type FooId = string & FooBrand
type BarId = string & BarBrand

const callFoo = (id: FooId) => {}

const b = 'bar' as BarId

callFoo(b); // now errors
```

You can read more about other nominal typing methods in the link above.

[Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nAQgJwIYgCZQN5QPpQC8UARCVAL4CwAUKJFIqsiulrgcWZbbQC4BPAA7BYCAJJZiAZz7IAliADmUAGRikaTP2GimySUSiyFytY2attNWgGM4IWVFuoANq-hwjACnkYAXBqSAJREAHw41DY09o58UABGRgDkCczJUKjSFgYYvDFuHgjeCcFAA)