# Trying to use nominal typing for id in typeorm typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, nominal-typing

I was following this article [TypeORM Best Practices using Typescript and NestJS at Libeo](https://medium.com/tales-of-libeo/typeorm-best-practices-using-typescript-and-nestjs-at-libeo-b02b7d1ed2eb).
I got to the point of using nominal typing in our entity ID

```
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
 id!: string & { __brand: "userId" };
```

but cannot use it in find operation example

```
async getUserById(id: User['id']) {
const user = await this.findOne({
  where: { id: 'id' },
});
return user;
```

},

I am having the following errors

```
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<User> | FindOptionsWhere<User>[] | undefined'.
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator<any> | never[] | EqualOperator<never> | undefined'.
       where: { id: 'id' },
```

Actually don't know what am doing wrong.

but if I remove the nominal part everything works very well

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
id!: string
```

I have also tried using just Primary Column

```
@PrimaryColumn("uuid")
id!: string & { __brand: "userId" };
```

Still not working. I think it has to do with the FindOption

Comment: What about [using enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139889/differentiate-between-different-strings-in-typescript/72143084#72143084)?

Comment: just write it in the find method without quotes as: 
  where: { id: id }

Answer (score 0):

```
enum UserIdBrand {
  __type = 'User',
}

type UserId = string & UserIdBrand;
```

@hittingonme Thanks

Also using enum didn't work, had to declare it as a type UserId